# Estimate $p$ of a Bernoulli after $n$ samples

Tags: mean, binomial-distribution, estimators, bernoulli-distribution

Suppose I extract $n$ samples $x_i$ from a Bernoulli distribution

$$x_i \sim Bern(p)$$

Based on the samples, I want to estimate the probability that $p$ is below a certain threshold $t$

$$P(p<t \space | \space x_1,\dots,x_n)$$

How do I go about it?

Comment: You're trying to write a probability statement that treats a parameter as a random variable. This doesn't  make sense in a frequentist framework, but does in a Bayesian one. For that. First you need some sort of prior on p.

Comment: I'm confident you can find answers by [searching our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=binomial%20beta%20conjugate%20prior&searchOn=3).  I have included enough relevant keywords to (greatly) narrow the hits.

Comment: @Glen_b  thank you -  ok let's take the prior $p=t$. I appreciate it calls for a Bayesian solution, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: A prior is a *distribution* on p. If you make it a degenerate distribution like that, the data will be ignored. You cannot be 100% certain that $p=t$ (or you wouldn't bother with data at all), so your prior clearly doesn't reflect your prior knowledge/beliefs. For a simple calculation, a beta prior would make your life easy. I'm not saying that you must go with that but since you're unfamiliar with Bayesian procedures, I'd suggest starting there, just to get the sense of what the objects are that you're dealing with.

Comment: If you do think $t$ is relevant, you might make a prior which relates to $t$ (has mean $t$, say), but with reasonably large uncertainty -- e.g. one that contributes only say about an observation's worth of information, perhaps. Though if you have a more specific uncertainty in mind you could do that. Alternatively you might consider an even lower-information prior, perhaps something like a Jeffreys' prior to get started with.

Comment: It sounds, however, like you either need to do some reading, or post a different question. There are many questions on site about basic Bayesian stats, but this may not be the best place to start learning the ideas, since it's a Q&A site (questions that could be answered in a few paragraphs), not a place for extensive tutorials.